# cygwin alias to C drive doesn't work

Tags: cygwin

I've created an alias in my bashrc like this:

```
alias workspace='/cygdrive/c/'
```

I thought I could use it in cygwin like cd workspace but then I get the error that
/cygdrive/c/ is a map.

I tried to delete / before cygdrive and after c but nothing works. Is it not possible to create an alias like this?

Comment: I did the full install so I guess yes. Cygwin doesn't complain about the extra rule in the bashrc..

Comment: Try '/cyg/c' rather than '/cygdrive/c'

Answer (score 1):

```
workspace=/cygdrive/c; cd $workspace
```

or

```
ln -s '/cygdrive/c' ~/workspace ; cd ~/workspace
```

but i still have no idea why some should use this

Answer (score 0):

It works for me: `alias workspace='cd /cygdrive/c/'`

Answer (score -1):

If you do it like this:
alias workspace='cd /cygdrive/c/Users/bla'

then you just need to type workspace and you're in the right directory :-)